# Makefile, main function, ClassNotFound

Tags: makefile, classnotfound

I have a Java program, and write a makefile to compile it on Linux.

My project organized like this (Run.java is the main entry)

```
Program - 
   Src - 
       (package)adb.Bing_WebResults
            Run.java
       (package)adb.jsonModel
            *.java
       (package)adb.models
            *.java
   bin - 

   lib - 
       gson.jar
       commons.jar

   resource -
       *.txt
```

This is my makefile:

```
# My project require 3 parameters from user input.

default: Run.class
Run.class: src/adb/Bing_WebResults/Run.java
    javac -sourcepath src/ -classpath lib/*.jar -d bin/ src/adb/Bing_WebResults/*.java  src/adb/jsonModels/*.java src/adb/models/*.java


run:
    java -classpath bin/:lib/*.jar  Run  "$(ARG1)" "$(ARG2)" "$(ARG3)"
```

When I use "make run" command in Linux terminate,  exception shows that "Could not find the main class: Run"

Are there something wrong with my makefile? Wrong path or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that could potentially be wrong, but the most apparent issues are the incorrect dependencies of the targets in your makefile.

First of all, the target `run` should have a dependency on `Run.class`. If you do `make run` then `make` looks at the target called `run`. In your `makefile`, this target does not have any dependencies defined, and it will execute the line `java ...` without checking whether the actual compiled class `Run.class` exists. As a consequence, if you do `make run` from a clean situation, your source code will not be compiled and the `java` command will fail because the compiled class is missing.

Your dependency of `default` on `Run.class` is incorrect as well, because `Run.class` will exist in the `bin` directory, not in the working directory. The line below mentions the target `Run.class` as well.

There are several ways to improve your makefile. See below an example of corrected code with some variables added to avoid repeated expressions. This approach is a matter of style and preference though.

```
BINDIR := bin
RUNCLASS := Run
RUNBINARY := $(BINDIR)/$(RUNCLASS).class
SRCDIR := src/adb/Bing_WebResults
RUNSRC := $(SRCDIR)/$(RUNCLASS).java

# Note: the default target below is superfluous at this moment
default: $(RUNBINARY)
$(RUNBINARY): $(RUNSRC)
        javac -sourcepath src/ -classpath lib/*.jar -d $(BINDIR) $(SRCDIR)/*.java src/adb/jsonModels/*.java src/adb/models/*.java

run: $(RUNBINARY)
        java -classpath $(BINDIR):lib/*.jar  $(RUNCLASS)  "$(ARG1)" "$(ARG2)" "$(ARG3)"
```

This works for me in a simplified, comparable setup -- it might work for you as well. Looking at the snippet you provided, there are most likely other dependencies or changes that need to be added to complete your `makefile` correctly. Potentially, you might have to add package information to your run command and dependency expressions, but that depends on your source code. Your post does not contain enough information to provide a complete solution.

P.S.: Do not forget to replace spaces by tabs if you copy this code to your own `makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

At last you need to specify the package when running since you dont seem to have the main class in default package.

```
java -classpath bin com.example.Run arg1 arg2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that two points should be noticed:
(1) Run is in a package, so it should be "adb.Bing_WebResults.Run.class" in makefile.

(2) external jar files should be concatenated by : (e.g.  lib/a.jar: lib/b.jar)

Comment: Good to read that you found those errors. Your makefile still needs corrections though. For example, if you do `make` multiple times, your code will be compiled multiple times, right?